# java spring microservice send realtime data/or dynamic variable to browser

Tags: java, spring, web, real-time, microservices

I am new to Java Spring microservice architecture. 
I have a sensor that sends every second a value: for example a `number=100, number=102, number=104,` ..... during a 30 min.

I have simple code that takes data from the sensor and returns a dynamic variable.

I can see it like this: `log.info("Data from sensor: "+number);`

And as a result we can see the output in the console:

Data from sensor: 100
Data from sensor: 102
Data from sensor: 104
.....

The question is What is a better way to show this variable using microservice architecture? What to write in Controller.class under `@GETMAPPING` ("/sampledata")
For example, when we run a simple microservice, it will show us a static data.
Browser: `localhost:1234/api/sampledata` . Browser will return us a final result "Hello, World!" or something like `"{Client=Josh, age=20, Surname=Siemens}"`.
But how to make the microservice, that will never stop and update the result?
For example, once opened Browser: `localhost:1234/api/sampledata` and on display we see the dynamic results:

Data from sensor: 100
like Temperature: 36 C

in 1-2 seconds the value will change.

Data from sensor : 102
like Temperature: 36,2 C

Any ideas how is it possible to do it? Maybe not only spring, maybe javascript or something like that??

Comment: First (and I think the better one) is to query the resource via Javascript on some intervals. Second is to never actually close the server connection and push continuous values in there (bad because server can only hold so many connections open at a time).

Comment: You can use Server Sent Events https://golb.hplar.ch/2017/03/Server-Sent-Events-with-Spring.html . With SSE you need some JavaScript code on the client side and some Java on the server side

Comment: Thank you for the help! All that things I have tried. And they are great for big projects. 
I have made it simplier. Just a value that goes in console for one variable.